# How much energy is in a lightning strike?

Tags: energy, electricity, lightning

According to Wikipedia an [average lightning strike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/lightening) has $1$ TW power, the [whole world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_generation#Production) used $16$ TW of power in 2006.

The lightning strike lasts for $30$ microseconds. Does this mean that you get $100$ TW of energy in just $30$ microseconds?

Comment: According to Doc Brown (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future), the energy contained is at least 1.21 gigawatts ;)

Comment: @akid: Jiggawatts is a measure of power, not energy.

Comment: Right! The linked wikipedia article states 1.2 GW energy though, and I'm not sure if it's actually wrong there or just citing a non-physical statement from the movie.

Comment: related: [Can energy be extracted from clouds?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19929/can-energy-be-extracted-from-clouds).

Comment: why is everybody stuck to a number given in the sci-fi movie? Has anybody really calculated the energy theoretically or experimentally?

Comment: People are joking and this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: If the world was connected to 16 lightning bolts at peak power continuously, it would be supplied with enough power on average. Unfortunately there are only 100 lightning strikes per second and they last very short. That's why we burn coal, that way we'll see more stormclouds in the future and we might just tip the scale in our favor.

Comment: More on [lightning as energy source](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+[lightning]+energy).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are confused about units. Watt is a unit of power (energy/time), Watt-hour is a unit of energy. 16TW is an estimate of the continuous average power usage of the world - which is about 140,000 TWh each year. If the lightning has a peak power of 1TW for 30 microseconds, this corresponds to an energy content of about 8000 Watt-hours.

Comment: In order to power the world, you would need to collect the energy of around 500,000 lightning strikes each second.

Comment: First of all, the current means nothing without a voltage specified.

Comment: Wikipedia says that the peak power is 1TW, for a period of 30 microseconds. Punch this into google: "1 terawatt * 30 microseconds in kilowatt hour". You get about 8KWh. Your bulb will consume about 150 KWh over 2 months of operation.

Comment: @50ndr33, your last comment gives the strong impression that you _don't_ understand the units. The values you're quoting are not consistent with each other. Perhaps you could read up on the definitions of power, current, and energy on Wikipedia or elsewhere, and feel free to ask questions on this site if there are parts that confuse you.

Comment: Ah, thanks for stating this. I've made a lot of notes here and mixed up some values.. You are perfectly correct: It's 1TW for 30 microseconds, not 1*100TW...

Comment: @50ndr33: ah, gotcha. You can always do things like rewrite $\text{TW}$ as $10^{12}\text{ W}$ if it helps. In any case, analyzing things like this is the perfect way to become comfortable with units and formulas. :-)

Comment: Yes, it's really interesting, but I'll have to leave it for the weekend, it's for a school project about lightnings and I have to make this stuff comprehendable for 30 persons, most of them not knowing more about electricity than how a circuit with a battery and a bulb works until Thursday.. There you have me struggling to keep up and thereafter simplify.. So I look forward to the weekend, when I can learn more.

Comment: My utility tells me my 2500 sq ft house consumes about 250 KWh/month. Applied Physics will drive it lower; my power usage is less than 1/3 US average. At 8.3 KWh per capture, one lightning strike/day might provide my power, but more conservation effort will take away more distractions. Conservation completely trumps added power generation in terms of improving life. We should not assume that the world's power needs are either fixed or increasing. Humans use cheap power to enable distracting fritterware and addictions to hysteria rather than doing martial arts, growing food, studying Physics...