# Why can't we harness the energy of lightning?

Tags: electricity, atmospheric-science, estimation, lightning

Studying capacitors, this question struck me. If we know that there is a large potential difference between the ground and the atmosphere, why dont we use that to power our machinery? I understand that lightning is the result of breakdown of the dielectric(air). Why dont we utilize this energy instead of letting it get neutralized into ground?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the lightning be captured and used as power source?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31254/)

Comment: I think this question is a little different than the earlier one. The earlier question asks if we can harness the energy of a lightning *strike*, but this new question is asking if we can harness the large potential difference that is already building up *before* it discharges as lightning.