# Electricity from lightning

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, photons, electric-current, lightning

1. According to the internet, a lightning strike contains about 5 billion joules or 5 GJ. How was this calculated?
2. Another thing: Once the lightning strike a metal grounded rod, a current will flow. What type of that current and how much current?  I think it will be a 325 MV current which is the voltage of the lightning. Is that correct?

   Edit: after i read a little bit about lightning , i found it was such a big scale , so how about a small electrostatic charge , say from a 1 MV van de graaff generator, i have a spark source ( my CRT TV :D ) and i will buy a multimeter and conduct some experiments , but i need to know what to expect

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76251/2451 and links therein.

Comment: You may be interested in reading more about [electric currents](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Current_vs_Voltage), and how they differ from voltages. Note, in particular, that current is *not* measured in volts. Otherwise, +1.

Comment: hahahaha :D  , i know....what i meant was that the current has a voltage of 325 MV, 325 MV in the clouds and 0 V in the ground

Comment: Current doesn't have voltage just like speed doesn't have horsepower.  They measure different things.  Before a lightning strike, there is a huge voltage difference between the clouds and the ground.  The presence of the voltage makes the current flow, but at the same time, the flow of the current makes the voltage go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The energy in a static discharge is 1/2 * voltage * charge.
For a 1MV VDG with a 1 meter sphere that's approximately 1/2 * 55µC * 1MV = 27.5J
However that's too much to do experiments safely. You should stay far below 1J.
Also mutimeters don't like sparks or high voltages of several kV.

Comment: 1- where did u get that equation? i understand the QV but why 1/2? 
2- i dont think it will hurt the multimeter , once i let the spark through a wire where an LED was connected , it lit and didn't burn

Comment: The equation for the energy can by found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance. The article also tells you how to calculate the self capacitance of a sphere. Also sparks can hurt a multimeter and even if they don't you will not be able to measure the current or voltage.

Comment: i know an easier way thought i would share it with u , instead of calculating C and then use C=Q/V just use V=QK/r where K is coulomb constant and r is the radius. 
oh...u broke my heart :D , so i cant experiment , i kinda need some information about that current , any idea about where i can find it?

Comment: For accurate measurements you need a digital storage oscilloscope with a high voltage probe. However I'm not sure what exactly you want to measure. The peak current of the spark?

Comment: yes, no problem , i will just a year or so , joining engineering school , i can use their equipment then , cuz i cant afford these stuff

Comment: You can not measure the current of a spark with a multimeter because it only lasts a tiny fraction of a second but there are other things a multimeter can measure. In a Van de Graaff generator for example you can measure the charging current. As long as you make sure that the meter is always at a low potential relativ to ground. And you should also connect a capacitor (around 0.1µF is enough) in parallel to the meter and maybe use the voltage range instead of the current range to measure the current. That allows you to measure smaller currents and gives you a higher input resistance.

Comment: thanks for the tip, so the current charging the sphere and discharging it resembles the charging and discharging of a capacitor?

Comment: Yes, a sphere has a capacitance and can be charged like a capacitor.

Comment: and discharges like a capacitor too?